# Fastest way to update a Postgres table, given a set of unique column values?

Tags: postgresql

I've been running into this same issue repeatedly when trying to execute Postgres updates.  First I'll run a SELECT query, like so:

```
SELECT stock_number
  FROM products
  WHERE available = true
EXCEPT
SELECT stock_number
  FROM new_inventory_list;
```

This selects the stock numbers of all products that indicate that they're available in the current database, but no longer appear in the new list of inventory that's just been downloaded.  This command runs very quickly.  However, virtually any method I use to update this list seems to take at least ten minutes to run, slowing the server down in the process. For instance:

```
UPDATE products
  SET available = false
  WHERE stock_number IN (
    SELECT stock_number
      FROM products
      WHERE available = true
      AND stock_number IS NOT NULL
    EXCEPT
    SELECT stock_number
      FROM new_inventory_list
    );
```

There are usually at least 10,000 rows that need to be updated, and often a lot more if a supplier pushes a lot of new inventory at once.  Additionally, we need to check for price updates.  It's relatively fast and easy to get a list of stock numbers for products that have been changed in price:

```
WITH overlap AS (
  SELECT stock_number
    FROM products
  INTERSECT
  SELECT stock_number
    FROM new_inventory_list
  )
unchanged AS (
  SELECT stock_number, price
    FROM products
  INTERSECT
  SELECT stock_number, price
    FROM new_inventory_list
  )
SELECT * FROM overlap EXCEPT SELECT stock FROM unchanged;
```

For this query, I don't even try to use SQL commands to do it, instead I pull the list out into a script, then run UPDATE on each modified value individually.  It's slow, but still seems to be faster than any command I've tried that was strictly in SQL.  Plus, with an external script, I can output the progress periodically, so I approximate how long it will run for.  Stock numbers are unique, although they're occasionally NULL. (Those should be ignored)

I feel like there has to be a much faster way of doing this, but so far I haven't had any luck figuring it out.  Any thoughts?

edit:

I think I found a better solution to this problem than any that I've tried so far:

```
WITH removed AS (
  SELECT stock_number
    FROM products
    WHERE available = true
  EXCEPT
  SELECT stock_number
    FROM new_inventory_list
  )
UPDATE products AS p
  SET available = false
  FROM removed
  WHERE removed.stock_number = p.stock_number;
```

I hadn't considered the idea of using `UPDATE` and `WITH` together, and didn't even know it was possible until I read the `UPDATE` documentation for Postgres.  Even though it's considerably faster, it still takes a few minutes to run, so to monitor it, I just run the above command in a loop, with `LIMIT 1000` at the end of the `SELECT` clause, printing a message to the console every time it successfully updates another block.

Comment: I would rewrite it, using EXISTS/NOT EXISTS instead of IN / EXCEPT.

Comment: I've tried that too.  It's faster than IN / EXCEPT but still slows to a crawl for anything significantly more complex than the first example I gave.

Comment: Try adding `AND available = True` to the where clause. It will avoid wasting too many row versions to the table. BTW is stock_number the PK for the products table ? `Stock numbers are unique, although they're occasionally NULL.` is suspect; it seems like a PK to me.

Comment: It seems you don't need the self-join at all (given that stock_number is unique)

Comment: Yeah, available = true is already in the WHERE clause in that version of the script.  I didn't want to complicate this post by writing out every variant I've tested so far, but yeah, I've tried that one too. stock_number is not the PK, another column is, which is our internal stock number.  (The stock_number column is the supplier stock number)

Comment: Without the data model and the exact problem definition this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data model is fairly complex, and would take a long time to explain.  There are about 50 columns, 20 of which are indexed, and there are between 500,000 and 1,000,000 rows at any given time.  I feel like there has to be a better way to update the data, since running updates from an external script (that is, pulling out a SELECT list, then looking up and updating each row individually) is often faster than any pure SQL solution.

Comment: Some sample data / schema would make a big difference for this question. Also, don't use `IN (...)` if possible; try to phrase it with `EXISTS (SELECT ...)` . Also try to rephrase that set-operation (`EXCEPT ...`) as an anti-join, using `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: I think I've got a better solution to this problem than any other one that I've tried so far.  Apparently you can combine WITH and UPDATE, which makes things quite a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
WITH removed AS (
  SELECT stock_number
    FROM products
    WHERE available = true
  EXCEPT
  SELECT stock_number
    FROM new_inventory_list
  )
UPDATE products AS p
  SET available = false
  FROM removed
  WHERE removed.stock_number = p.stock_number;
```

… will, I trust, do a superfluous join on the ***entire*** table with itself. And probably a poorly performing one, at that, because of the `except` clause in the `with` statement.

Think of it this way: suppose a products table with a million rows, around 250k marked as available, and 50k of those that don't appear in a 200k-item strong inventory list. The `with` query runs like this: 1) find the 50k rows in products that need to be updated; 2) then, *for each row in products*, check if the id is in those 50k rows in order to ***re***-select those same 50k rows; 3) and update the row.

For improved performance, the update query should select the candidate rows from products that need to be updated *directly*, and use an anti-join to eliminate unwanted rows. The query @wildplasser posted earlier seems fine:

```
UPDATE products dst
SET available = false
WHERE available
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM new_inventory_list nx
    WHERE nx.stock_number = dst.stock_number
    );
```

Another point is the "about 50 columns, 20 of which are indexed" you mentioned in the comments: That will slow down updates considerable. Imagine: each row that gets updated needs to be written into not just *that* table, but in an additional *20* tables. Are you sure this shouldn't be normalized a bit more and that you actually need each of those indexes?

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly the code I posted runs faster than the code @wildplasser posted, but it does, considerably.  The `SELECT` clause that uses `EXCEPT` only takes about 1-2 seconds to run by itself.  It could have something to with all the indexed columns, or maybe Postgres optimized some of the inefficiency of my command.  As far as the 20 indexed columns, they are actually necessary, due to the large number of complex lookup queries that are constantly being run on it.  Since inventory is only updated once a day, it's not a huge problem if it takes 20-30 minutes to do the updating.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
WITH removed AS (
  SELECT stock_number
    FROM products p1
    LEFT JOIN new_inventory_list n1
    ON p1.stock_number=n1.stock_number
    WHERE p1.available AND n1.stock_number IS NULL
  )
```

I don't know how the `EXCEPT` is being done; perhaps this will retain some indexing for use in the `UPDATE`. Also, if `available` is usually false, I would add a partial index

```
CREATE INDEX product_available ON product(stock_number) WHERE available;
```